# Bad redirectUrl at login with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This is what I did to reproduce my problem:

1. Login (redirection at page foo)
2. Click and go to page bar
3. Logout
4. Login again
5. The redirected page is bar (it should be foo)

This is what I did:

**AppController.php**

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authorize' => ['Controller'],
    'loginRedirect' => [
        'controller' => 'Dashboard',
        'action' => 'index'
    ]
]);
```

**UsersController.php**

```
public function login($reset = null) {
    $this->layout = 'login';
    $this->set('reset', $reset);

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $user = $this->Auth->identify();

        if ($user) {  
            // IMPORTANT!
            // Here I'm setting a different redirect url. The book says
            // that $this->Auth->redirectUrl() will read the Auth.redirect
            // session. I wanted my admin to login into a different page  
            if($session->read('Auth.User.role_id') === 3) {
                $session->write('Auth.redirect', '/users/system_administrator_index');
            }

            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());

        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('Oops', ['key' => 'auth']);
        }
    }
}

public function logout() {        
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

I tried to use `$session->destroy();` in order to clear everything related to my session but I noticed anything.

Each time I retry to login, the server redirect me to the last page I visited the last time I was connected.

Comment: Is `Auth->redirect` set in your session between step 3 and 4 ?

Comment: Try `$this->redirect('Dashboard');`

Comment: @Jun: No, I did exactly like the blog tutorial. The only session I tried to modify is the Auth.redirect in the login function. CakePHP doesn't seems to like when we touch sessions directly if we are using the Auth component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround. Instead of using `return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());`, I do a manual redirection.

```
public function login($reset = null) {
    $this->layout = 'login';
    $this->set('reset', $reset);

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();

        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);

            if($user['role_id'] === 3){
                return $this->redirect('/users/system_administrator_index');
            }

            return $this->redirect('/dashboard');
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('Oops', ['key' => 'auth']);
        }
    }
}
```